# get FULL hardware configuration of a VM from powercli

Tags: command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, powercli

I want to export the complete hardware configuration of a vm to the console via PowerCLI. `Get-VM` seems to only have limited information based on a `Get-VM xxx | Get-Member` check. In vCenter, if you right click on a vm and select "Edit Settings" you get a GUI based breakdown of the entire virtual hardware config of the VM. I want to output that exact information to the console.

I know `Get-View` will let me access the plethora of API's which contain this information, however, at that point I am just writing my own cmdlet from scratch which is a ton of work.